# A sum of rasters in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap

I have daily SO2 data (the worldwide data) and after some processing I have to sum 30 rasters.

What the tool can you recommend to use for this goal within ArcMap tools?

I tried Raster calculator ("rast 1"+"rast 2"+...), but it doesn't give me the raster with the sum of pixel values.

Also I tried Image analysis (Mosaic tool), but still no the result I need to obtain.

Furthermore the summarizing by Raster calculator causes the missing of some values in different parts of the map.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is the Cell Statistics tool. This can calculate the sum of a bunch of rasters. You can find it in the 'Spatial Analyst' - 'Local' toolbox. This tool can also work around NoData values in your dataset.

Comment: Thanks! I might thought too much about the Raster calculator and forgot about the Cell Statistics. It's indeed the tool I need.